# Table display code is showing wrong column

Tags: python

I have written a program that displays which countries are classified as "very high", "high", " medium", or "low" on human development. Countries will be classified as follows:

1. "very high" , 0.75 < HDI score
2. "high"........., 0.51 < HDI < 0.75
3. "medium"..., 0.26 < HDI < 0.5
4. "low"...........,............HDI < 0.26

The result should look like:

```
Country  HDI score
Japan 0.903
Finland 0.895
Qatar 0.856
Lebanon 0.763
Armenia 0.743
Iraq 0.649
Pakistan 0.550
Djibouti 0.473
Cameroon 0.518
```

with this code I wrote:

```
Country=   ["Japan","Finland","Qatar","Lebanon","Armenia","Iraq","Pakistan",
            "Djibouti","Cameroon"]
Country[0]=0.903
Country[1]=0.895
Country[2]=0.856
Country[3]=0.763
Country[4]=0.743
Country[5]=0.649
Country[6]=0.550
Country[7]=0.473
Country[8]=0.518
for Country in Country:
    if Country>0.76:
        print [Country, "Very High"]
    elif 0.76>Country>0.51:
        print [Country,"High"]
    elif 0.51>Country>0.26:
        print [Country,"Medium"]
    elif Country < 0.26:
        print [Country,"Low"]
```

But the problem with that code is that, it displays the HDI's and the rank rather than the country's name and the rank as follows:

```
[0.903, 'Very High']
[0.895, 'Very High']
[0.856, 'Very High']
[0.763, 'Very High']
[0.743, 'High']
[0.649, 'High']
[0.55, 'High']
[0.473, 'Medium']
[0.518, 'High']
```

I don't get what I am missing here, why does it print the HDI rather than the country's name equivalent for it, although i introduced the names of the countries as the very first thing.

Comment: `Country` is a list that you first put the country names into, but then you overwrite each item in the list with the HDI.

Comment: You need to define a nested structure, not a singular flat array.

Comment: You defined country as a list: `Country=   ["Japan","Finland" ...]` when it looks like you want a dictionary: `Country=   {"Japan": 0.903,"Finland": 0.895, ...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem a few things to go wrong here...

Your using `for Country in Country`.. statement...(very confusing to me). Anyway use **Countries** for listname:

```
Countries = ["Japan","Finland","Qatar","Lebanon","Armenia","Iraq","Pakistan",
             "Djibouti","Cameroon"]

Countries[0]=0.903  # overriding in Countries the 'Japan' Country name with the value '0.903'
... snippet...

for Country in Countries:
    ...snippet...
```

Your also almost mixing lists and dicts. Lets stick to lists + tuples.

Try:

```
Countries = [('Japan', 0.903), (country, value), etc...]
```

Then you get:

```
for country in Countries:
    my_country_name  = country[0]
    my_country_value = country[1]

    if my_country_value >0.76:
        print [my_country_name, "Very High"]
    elif ... :
        print ...
    etc..
    ..snippet...
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `list` to define the countries and their HDIs, but you are modifying the list when you are putting HDI values in, rather than attaching a value to each country.

Let's take a quick look at what's going on with a few of your early steps:

```
Country = ["Japan",
           "Finland", 
           "Qatar",
           "Lebanon",
           "Armenia",
           "Iraq",
           "Pakistan",
           "Djibouti",
           "Cameroon"]
```

If I define that and then print it out in a Python shell:

```
> print Country
['Japan', 'Finland', 'Qatar', 'Lebanon', 'Armenia', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Djibouti', 'Cameroon']
```

All looks good.

But then if I run your next line of code:

```
> Country[0]=0.903
```

Let's print it out again:

```
> print Country
[0.903, 'Finland', 'Qatar', 'Lebanon', 'Armenia', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Djibouti', 'Cameroon']
```

We just replaced `Japan` with `0.903`, because you replaced the original value in the `Country` list when you did `Country[0]`.

So what you really want is something that relates each country to their respective HDI value. One way to do this would be to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), which associates a something to something else.

The basic syntax to use a dictionary would be:

```
countries = { 'Japan': 0.903,
              'Finland': 0.895,
              # etc
            }
```

And then you can iterate over it by key, and use the values. Here's your code adapted to use a dictionary and that iterates over the dictionary using its keys and values.

```
countries = {
    'Japan': 0.903,
    'Finland': 0.895,
    'Qatar': 0.856,
    'Lebanon': 0.763,
    'Armenia': 0.743,
    'Iraq': 0.649,
    'Pakistan': 0.550,
    'Djibouti': 0.473,
    'Cameroon': 0.518
}

for country, hdi in countries.iteritems():
    if hdi > 0.76:
        print [country, "Very High"]
    elif 0.76 > hdi > 0.51:
        print [country,"High"]
    elif 0.51 > hdi > 0.26:
        print [country,"Medium"]
    elif hdi < 0.26:
        print [country,"Low"]
```

The output will look like:

```
['Pakistan', 'High']
['Qatar', 'Very High']
['Iraq', 'High']
['Armenia', 'High']
['Japan', 'Very High']
['Finland', 'Very High']
['Lebanon', 'Very High']
['Djibouti', 'Medium']
['Cameroon', 'High']
```

You will notice the ordering is different from your original list. The normal dictionary doesn't keep insertion order.

Notice some stylistic things I did:

- I use lower-case names for the variable
- I don't use the same variable to refer to different things like you did for `Country`
- More spacing in the mathematical comparisons

Answer (score 0):

## or...

```
country = [
    ("japan", 0.903),
    ("Finland", 0.895),
    ("Qatar", 0.856),
    ("Lebanon", 0.763),
    ("Armenia", 0.743),
    ("Iraq", 0.649),
    ("Pakistan", 0.550),
    ("Djibouti", 0.473),
    ("Cameroon", 0.518)
]

v1 = ''
for c, v in country:
    if v < 0.26:
        v1 = "very low"
    elif v > 0.26 and v < 0.51:
        v1 = "low"
    elif v > 0.51 and v < 0.76:
        v1 = "High"
    else:
        v1 = "Very High"
    print("{:10} {:6} {:10}".format(c, v, v1))
```

> output

```
japan       0.903 Very High 
Finland     0.895 Very High 
Qatar       0.856 Very High 
Lebanon     0.763 Very High 
Armenia     0.743 High      
Iraq        0.649 High      
Pakistan     0.55 High      
Djibouti    0.473 low       
Cameroon    0.518 High
```